# Why does dask.distributed auto memory trimming not work?

Tags: memory-leaks, dask, distributed

The unmanaged memory usage is high when I'm read files and process the data. After manually triggering the memory trimming function, the unmanaged memory usage decrease significantly.

```
import ctypes

def trim_memory() -> int:
    libc = ctypes.CDLL("libc.so.6")
    return libc.malloc_trim(0)
client.run(trim_memory)
```

However, I tried automatically trim memory by:

1. Set the `MALLOC_TRIM_THRESHOLD_` = 0
2. Modify `distributed/distributed.yaml` `nanny: MALLOC_TRIM_THRESHOLD_=0`
3. Send env to worker when starting client `client=Client(env={"MALLOC_TRIM_THRESHOLD_":0})`
   All these efforts seems fail, the unmanaged memory usage stay on the peak level.

What should be the right way to trim memory?

Comment: Could you please also share some details about your setup -- your operating system, the versions of dask, distributed, python, etc.? It'll help in diagnosing the issue :)

Comment: What kind of data are you dealing with predominantly? Is it pure-python objects, numpy/pandas, or other? If it's numpy/pandas, what is the chunk size, in bytes? From past experience, the problem suddenly disappears once you pass a certain threshold in chunk size.

Comment: Also, what does this return? ``client.run(os.getenv, "MALLOC_TRIM_THRESHOLD_")``

Answer (score 2):

Reproduced.
Issue tracker and simple workaround until it is fixed:
https://github.com/dask/distributed/issues/5971